# Ubuntu doesn't start gdm3 and enters tty1 on boot

Tags: boot, gnome, login, gdm

I've been tweaking with my system appearance lately, and wanted to change Gnome's Display manager and change the login screen theme.

After boot, the display shows the following for few seconds:

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 754129/10690560 files, 13222358/42732800 
Started bpfilter
```

Quickly followed By:

```
Ubuntu 19.04 muathasus tty1

muathasus login: muath
Password :
Last login: Sat Jun 15 15:16:42 IDT 2019 on tty1
Welcome to Ubuntu 19.04 (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-16-generic x86_64)

* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management : https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support : https://ubuntu.com/advantage

* Ubunta’s Kubernetes 1.14 distributions can bypass Docker and use containerd directly, see https://bit. ly/ubuntu-containerd or try it now with

    snap install microk8s —-classic

3 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.

muath@muathasus:~$
```

Pressing `ctrl-alt-f1` or `ctrl-alt-f7` have no effect.
I could continue to desktop manually by writing `startx` or by `sudo service start gdm3`.

I have Ubuntu 19.04 with X.org drivers, and haven't upgraded lately.
Also tried to switch from gdm3 to lightdm or to slim, with no effect.

Additional:

Output of `systemctl status gdm.service` include:

```
Jun 15 16:14:56 muathasus gdm-password][3554]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

Trying to change gnome's display manager using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` returns

```
Error: can't open /lib/modules/5.0.0-15-generic/update/dkms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it, it appeared to me that `systemctl get-default` returns `multi-user.target`. I don't know what this affects and how, but I changed the default to graphical.target:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

and it just works now!